# WCF how to detect if client and server are in same server

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a service with multiple endpoints. These endpoints get requests from clients, and from each other too.

For the methods that gets the request from the other endpoints I need to make sure that the method can only be invoked from within the server.

I already have an authentication filter interception mechanism. I can bind this functionality to those certain methods. What I cannot figure out is how can I tell the request made from the same server. Take a look at below code snippet that I use for authentication:

```
public class ServiceUser_Authenticator : IParameterInspector
{
    public object BeforeCall ( string operationName, object[] inputs )
    {
        var ip = ( OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty ).Address;

        if ( ip != /* 127.0.0.1 , localhost , RealIP of the server */ )
            throw new FaultException("Access denied");

        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

I am thinking to check if the ip of the client is same as mine, but don't know how. The `RealIP(external)` will probably work, but it better be a non-static value.

So, how can I check if the client of a wcf call is in the same server as wcf service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my humble opinion, the easiest and safest way to make some methods to be invoked only locally is to use `NetNamedPipeBinding`.

So I would take all the "local" methods and put them in a separate interface.
And I would expose that interface with  `NetNamedPipeBinding`.

**Edit**
You can expose **different** interfaces on the **same service**.
Each interface can have its own binding.

**Edit 2 - code samples**

In the two following samples, here is the service class exposing two interfaces

```
class ServiceHelloWorld : IPublicInterface, ILocalInterface
```

**1. Many  endpoints can be exposed through xml**
These aren't the same interfaces. :

```
<services>
  <service name="HelloWorldService.ServiceHelloWorld">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:7000/publicinterface" 
      binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IPublicInterface">
    <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost:8000/privateinterface" 
      binding="netNamedBinding" contract="ILocalInterface">
  </service>
</services>
```

**2. Many  endpoints can be exposed through code**

These aren't the same interfaces no more.

```
ServiceHost host =
   new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceHelloWorld), new Uri[] { });
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPublicInterface), 
   new NetTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://localhost:7000/publicinterface");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ILocalInterface), 
   new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost:8000/privateinterface");
```

Regards

Comment: I am using a live list to hold the online clients callback channels in order to send notifications to them arbitrarily. Therefore I need to have those methods in the same service instance. I think easiest won't do the job in my case :)

Comment: It will do the job. I am not on my work computer. But I can show you the config code as soon as I reach it if you need to. Just tell. Regards

Comment: I'll be glad if you show me the config, even if I still am not convinced about this method that'll be great if I learn a way to manage this. BTW we may need to continue this discussion on chat.

Comment: I didn't know we could use the endpoints like this. So it will be a service with two(or more) doors open to different ways. That'll do the job.